# DeadObjectException When trying to use Context.sendOrderedBroadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm using [Context.sendOrderedBroadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendOrderedBroadcast%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.os.Handler,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29) method to send a broadcast and check if anyone has received it before getting to the resultReceiver.

Here's a code snippet :

```
context.sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null, new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
  // Do something if this broadcast was not handled by others.
}, null, Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
```

This usually works with no problem but from time to time I get the following error and my BroadcastReceiver is not called :

> W/ActivityManager(12067): Failure sending broadcast result
>   of Intent { act=... }
>   W/ActivityManager(12067): android.os.DeadObjectException
>   W/ActivityManager(12067):     at
>   android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
>   W/ActivityManager(12067):     at
>   android.content.IIntentReceiver$Stub$Proxy.performReceive(IIntentReceiver.java:121)
>   W/ActivityManager(12067):     at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.performReceive(ActivityManagerService.java:12912)
>   W/ActivityManager(12067):     at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.processNextBroadcast(ActivityManagerService.java:13133)W/ActivityManager(12067):     at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.finishReceiver(ActivityManagerService.java:12766)
>   W/ActivityManager(12067):     at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:287)
>   W/ActivityManager(12067):     at
>   com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1755)
>   W/ActivityManager(12067):     at
>   android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:301)
>   W/ActivityManager(12067):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

So far I only encountered it on Motorola Defy phones with Android version 2.1, but it might happen to others as well.

I could not find any reference to it on the internet, does anyone know why this happens?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see this happening if the component that called `sendOrderedBroadcast()` was destroyed prior to the broadcast winding its way back to the supplied instance of the `BroadcastReceiver` anonymous subclass.

Comment: Yes, I switched to use a non-anonymous BroadcastReceiver class and so far it works like a charm.